# Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.BACK) doesn't work

Tags: android, libgdx

Here my code:
    package com.mygdx.game;

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
   SpriteBatch batch;
   Texture img;

   @Override
   public void create () {
        Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
      batch = new SpriteBatch();
      img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");

   }

   @Override
   public void render () {
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.BACK)) {
            Gdx.app.log("Debug", "Back pressed!");
            Gdx.app.exit();
        }
      Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
      Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      batch.begin();
      batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
      batch.end();
   }
}
```

I have no idea why the code doesn't working as expected, when i replace "isKeyJustPressed" with "isKeyPressed" it works perfectly.
Or replace the Keys.Back with Keys.ESCAPE (run on desktop module) its work.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keys.BACK isnt probably what you are looking for. Try Keys.BACKSPACE

Comment: i try to catch BACK_KEY event on android phone, so Keys.BACK is the only option